# How to display image on button

Tags: c++, winapi

I created a button and I want to display an image on it. After some research I found the following code:

```
HBITMAP buttonImage;
buttonImage = (HBITMAP)LoadImageW(NULL,L"Button.bmp",IMAGE_BITMAP,95,35,LR_LOADFROMFILE);
HWND playBTN = CreateWindow(TEXT("button"),NULL,WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_BITMAP,330, 400, 95, 35, hwnd, (HMENU)1, NULL, NULL);
SendMessageW(playBTN,BM_SETIMAGE,IMAGE_BITMAP,(LPARAM) buttonImage);
```

The code runs succesfuly but there isnt any change at the button

I also tried using `LR_DEFAULTCOLOR`,`LR_VGACOLOR`and `LR_LOADMAP3DCOLORS` but nothing changed.

Note: The image I want to display is a box with green color

Comment: Did you verify that `LoadImageW()` is not returning a `NULL` handle to begin with? That being said, given the simplistic nature of your image, it may be easier to just give the button the `BS_OWNERDRAW` style and then draw your own green box directly onto the button in response to the `WM_DRAWITEM` message, no `.bmp` file needed.

Comment: The ```LoadImageW()``` doesnt return as ```NULL```,but  I will try what you suggest me

Comment: *"I found the following code"* - Obvious first question then: Do you also understand the code? It is creating a button, but later you say that you want a (presumably existing) button to change. It would help to see a [mcve].

Comment: @IInspectable I know i am creating a new button, thats the button I am using in my code as well.